Are right kites cyclic?
According to Wikipedia "Kite_(geometry) - Special Cases": "The right kites are exactly the kites that are cyclic quadrilaterals."
But according to "Quadrilateral - Taxonomy", kites are tangential but not cyclic!
Which is it?

Right kites are not all kites. Right kites aren't listed anywhere on the taxonomy diagram.

Note that whoever constructed that taxonomy in Wikipedia listed three special cases of trapezoid in addition to the general case of a trapezoid. If they had not listed all those special cases, we would not know that there are trapezoids that are cyclic but are not rectangles. Since they did not take the trouble to single out any special cases of kites other than the rhombus, they couldn't tell us about cyclic kites. You can't take diagrams like this as proofs of non-existence of the things not listed.

Note that in a right kite, the kite is symmetrical over its diagonal across from the right angle. This means both sides are congruent. That diagonal, being opposite of a right angle, is hence the diameter of the inscribing circle. So right kites are always cyclic.
